# Flask request.files is empty

Tags: python, flask

much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589649/why-request-files-is-empty), I'm trying to follow the [simple Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) for file upload to a flask server. In my specific case, I'm trying to upload an XML file.

The (simplified) HTML I'm using is:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Let's go!">
</form>
```

The request is correctly handled by a `if request.method == 'POST':` block, so I put in some print statements to troubleshoot:

```
print('request.method', request.method)
print('request.args', request.args)
print('request.form', request.form)
print('request.files', request.files)
```

and the result was the following:

```
request.method POST
request.args ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.form ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.files ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

What am I doing wrong? I can provide more complete source code if needed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As always, I found the answer mere minutes after posting this question. I'm answering here to hopefully help someone else.

The problem was that my file input had no `name` attribute. [Thanks to Ben here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13214650/6894799) I was able to fix this problem by adding a `name` attribute to the file input, and now the file upload is being processed correctly.

Comment: For anyone else who is directed to this question through searching, `request.files` will also return empty if you don't set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form (which you did). I know this doesn't apply to your specific situation, which is why I'm leaving it as a comment and not an answer, but it's another good reason for `request.files` to appear empty.