# Python flask upload file using ajax request.files empty

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I am trying to upload an image about 1.62MB to an end point written using flask. the request.files object is always empty. I've checked the following questions but no luck:

- [Flask request.files is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108907/flask-request-files-is-empty)
- https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2505
- [How to upload a file using an ajax call in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334717/how-to-upload-a-file-using-an-ajax-call-in-flask)

here is my server:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = r"C:\Temp"
app.debug = True

@app.route("/demo-upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def ProcessImage():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.files)
        try:
            if 'file' in request.files:
                with open("test-upload.png", "wb") as iFile:
                    print(request['file'])
                    iFile.write(request.files['file'])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return jsonify("Ok")

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def DemoIndexPage():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

my client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center">Status Demo</h1>
    <span>upload image to process.</span><br/>
        <form id="FileForm" name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="File" />
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="ProcessImage()" />
        </form>
    <p id="status" hidden>Success!</p>
    <script>
        function ProcessImage()
        {
            var form_data = new FormData($('#File')[0]);
            console.log(form_data)
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/demo-upload',
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Success!');
                    $("#status").show();
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

everything looks clean to me and I do not know where I am going wrong. the files attribute in the request object is always empty. I also tried with postman using post request with form-data key = file and value = uploaded a file, and a header content-type = "multipart/form-data". any help is appreciated thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a few changes and make it work:

First, change which html element you read the data from in javascript part:

```
var formDataRaw = $('#FileForm')[0];
var form_data = new FormData(formDataRaw);
```

Second, I tried to obtain the uploaded image as follows: (@cross_origin() is only required if you try to upload to your localhost)

```
@app.route("/demo-upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@cross_origin()
def ProcessImage():
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.files)
        try:
            if 'file' in request.files:
                imageFile = request.files['file']
                savePath = "/somewhere/somewhere/something.png"
                imageFile.save(savePath)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return jsonify("Ok")
```

Comment: frankly, while trying to solve this I tried these changes without the cross origin decorator and it did not work for me. I am going to copy paste your code though and give it a try. I got it working through using form's submit but I wanted to use AJAX instead of form submit. thanks a lot