# Axios sends CSV file but not Excel file

Tags: javascript

I'm using `Axios` to send a `POST` request with a file being sent as formdata.

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', file)
axios(myUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    data: formData,
})
```

I'm then reading in the file on a `Flask` server by accessing `request.files`.

When sending a CSV file, it works as expected, however when sending an Excel file the `request.files` list is empty.

I've isolated the issue to my front end API call -- because when sending that same request with the Excel file using Postman, my server reads it correctly.

*Things I've considered:*
I've read posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108907/flask-request-files-is-empty) suggesting that Flask can't detect files if the `file.name` property is null on the front end.

However, here when I `console.log(file)` for the CSV file I get:

```
{
    lastModified: 1693778248250,
    lastModifiedDate: Sun Sep 03 2023 17:57:28 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {},
    name: "test_dummy.csv",
    size: 39358,
    type: "text/csv",
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

And the Excel sheet I get:

```
{
    lastModified: 1695170579467,
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Sep 19 2023 20:42:59 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {},
    name: "my_custom_dataset.xlsx",
    size: 73961,
    type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

Point being, both files having the same properties and value types.

With that in mind, why might this API call work for a CSV file but fail with an Excel file

Comment: I've isolated the issue further to a middleware package I'm using to proxy HTTP requests `next-http-proxy-middleware`. For some reason the Excel file is getting dropped within the proxy but the CSV is not

Comment: Perhaps a size issue as the Excel file is larger

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with a library I'm using to proxy HTTP requests, `next-http-proxy-middleware`. This library has open issues mentioned in their docs regarding sending multipart/form-data requests. The body parser messes with certain filetypes and can be turned off to fix it.

I needed to update my config for that proxy to set `bodyParser: false`

```
export const config = {
    api: {
        // Enable `externalResolver` option in Next.js
        externalResolver: true,
        bodyParser: false,
    },
}
```

See issues [here](https://github.com/stegano/next-http-proxy-middleware/issues/33) and merged PR [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/7686) for further details.